# Why can I use "\" to write commands over two lines, but not more than two?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner learning Python, and I am wondering why

```
q = 1 + \
2
```

executes correctly and creates the variable q and assigns it the value 3 over two lines, but

```
xv\
a\
1\
= 1 + \
2
```

fails to execute, creating the variable xva1 and assigning it the value 3 over 5 lines as my book (*A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling*) states it should. I've tried variations of the spacing before and after the \ to no avail, since I discovered online Python is very sensitive to it.

Any help explaining why the second command fails would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can't use line continuation in the middle of an identifier or other token, it's only syntactically valid between tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing commands over more than two lines is perfectly doable.

```
x\
=\
1\
+\
1
```

works fine. The issue isn't the number of lines; the issue is *tokenization*. Python tokenizes your code long before it tries to parse it, and a backslash-newline sequence is treated as whitespace. So consider your example

```
xv\
a\
1\
= 1 + \
2
```

You *want* it to be seen as

```
xva1 = 1 + 2
```

But in reality, the backslash-newlines get treated as whitespace, so it gets seen as

```
xv a 1 = 1 + 2
```

which is, needless to say, not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Okay, so basically the use of \ creates a whitespace, and you can only validly use it to continue a string of code into multiple lines if there otherwise would be a space at that end of that line?

Is the book just wrong here? I'm curious as well how one might define a variable 'xval1' and assign it a value, say 3, over more than two lines, then.

Comment: Correct. In the `xval1` example, the characters "x", "v", "a", "l", and "1" have to be on the same line. Everything else is open season: the `=` and `3` could be on separate lines if you wanted.